# How can I include files using node?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I want to include raw files for example

If I have index.htm

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    <node include file.js>
  </script>
  <node include file.htm>
</body>
```

Obviously there is no node tag like there is a php tag?  Is there a reason for this.

What is the node way?

Comment: How are you serving your `index.htm` file?

Comment: Node.js runs on the server -- why do you want to include node files in your html output?

Comment: ... guys the same way in php you can do a `<?php include file.ext >` ... the server parses the file and creates the output ... what is the javascript / node equivalent?

Comment: Please state why you want to use node to inject the file rather than a normal script tag? Otherwise I think this is pretty clearly VTC.